# Minimize loop optimization

Tags: export, mathematical-optimization, infinite-loop

I'm new in *Mathematica* 10.

So far, I have a two variable-function and I've use Minimize to find the optimal solution.

Nevertheless, I'd like to make a sensibility analysis and study how this optimal solution behaves, doing a "For" cycle changing some coefficient of this function and keeping all the optimal solution in a table or matrix.

Is that possible to do?  I've tried using a For cycle but I don't know how to save the optimal value in an auxiliary variable.

For instance :

```
Table[NMinimize[{a x + b y, 0.2 x + 0.1 y >= 14, 0.25 x + 0.6 y >= 30, 
    0.1 x + 0.15 y >= 10, x >= 0, y >= 0}, {x, y}][[2]], {a, 0, 3, 1}, {b, 0, 3, 1}]
```

Does anyone one how to save all of the X and Y Values in only 2 columns? I'd like to associate those columns to de corresponding value of a and b

Comment: Please read the documentation for [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html), then if necessary edit your question with what you tried and in what way it did not work.  (I will reopen the question at that time.)

Comment: Perhaps this: `TableForm[
Table[NMinimize[{a x+b y,0.2 x+0.1 y>=14,0.25 x+0.6 y>=30,0.1 x+0.15 y>=10,x>=0,y>=0},{x,y}][[1]],{a,0,2,0.2},{b,0,3,0.3}],
TableHeadings->{"a = "<>ToString[#]&/@Range[0,2,0.2],"b = "<>ToString[#]&/@Range[0,3,0.3]}]`?

Comment: Thank you! @seismatica I'd like to save the x and y value too. I've thought in 5 columns, a,b,x,y and CT. I'm gonna review the table information of this software. thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've already modified the post. Is that enough to modify the condition of this post?

Comment: @YoJesseP Done.

Comment: Is this what you want? `TableForm[Table[Grid[NMinimize[{a x+b y,0.2 x+0.1 y>=14,0.25 x+0.6 y>=30,0.1 x+0.15 y>=10,x>=0,y>=0},{x,y}]/.{axby_,{x->xp_,y->yp_}}:>{{"x","y","ax+by"},{xp,yp,axby}},Frame->All],{a,0,3,1},{b,0,3,1}],TableHeadings->{"a = "<>ToString[#]&/@Range[0,2,0.2],"b = "<>ToString[#]&/@Range[0,3,0.3]}]`. I don't know what CT is but I assume it is the same as ax + by.

Comment: Sorry, the table heading for that is wrong. It should be this: `TableForm[Table[Grid[NMinimize[{a x+b y,0.2 x+0.1 y>=14,0.25 x+0.6 y>=30,0.1 x+0.15 y>=10,x>=0,y>=0},{x,y}]/.{axby_,{x->xp_,y->yp_}}:>{{"x","y","ax+by"},{xp,yp,axby}},Frame->All],{a,0,3,1},{b,0,3,1}],TableHeadings->{"a = "<>ToString[#]&/@Range[0,3,1],"b = "<>ToString[#]&/@Range[0,3,1]}]`

Comment: @seismatica Sorry. I deleted the CT function. Yes, CT[x,y] is ax+by. But what I want, is a table with 5 columns: a,b, x,y and optimal value. Below this headings I'd like to complete the table with the value of a,b and x,y and de Minimal CT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
Grid[Prepend[
  Flatten[Table[{a, b, 
      Reverse@NMinimize[{a x + b y, 0.2 x + 0.1 y >= 14, 
         0.25 x + 0.6 y >= 30, 0.1 x + 0.15 y >= 10, x >= 0, 
         y >= 0}, {x, y}]}, {a, 0, 3, 1}, {b, 0, 3, 1}] /. {ap_, 
      bp_, {{x -> xp_, y -> yp_}, axbyp_}} :> {ap, bp, xp, yp, axbyp},
    1], {"a", "b", "x", "y", "CT"}], Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This strikes me as a bit more complicated that necessary but it gets the job done. +1

Comment: I just realized that I didn't need `Reverse` since I'm pattern-matching the output anyway. I really don't know if post-processing this way is a bad habit or not.

Comment: Thank you! this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Generally I don't think there is anything wrong with it unless performance is critical (in which case `Part` will be faster if you can find a way to apply it) but `NMinimize` is returning Rules specifically to make their substitution easier so you might as well use them.

Comment: True. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but in an effort to demonstrate some possibilities:

```
Join @@ Table[{{a, b}, 
    NMinimize[{a x + b y, 0.2 x + 0.1 y >= 14, 0.25 x + 0.6 y >= 30, 0.1 x + 0.15 y >= 10,
        x >= 0, y >= 0}, {x, y}][[2]]}, {a, 0, 3, 1}, {b, 0, 3, 1}] // Column
```

Or:

```
Join @@ Table[{{HoldForm[a] -> a, HoldForm[b] -> b}, 
    NMinimize[{a x + b y, 0.2 x + 0.1 y >= 14, 0.25 x + 0.6 y >= 30, 0.1 x + 0.15 y >= 10,
        x >= 0, y >= 0}, {x, y}][[2]]}, {a, 0, 3, 1}, {b, 0, 3, 1}] // MatrixForm
```

---

Based on your comment perhaps:

```
expr =
  {a x + b y, 0.2 x + 0.1 y >= 14, 0.25 x + 0.6 y >= 30, 0.1 x + 0.15 y >= 10, x >= 0, y >= 0};

tab =
  Table[
    {a, b, x, y, #} /. #2 & @@ NMinimize[expr, {x, y}],
    {a, 0, 3}, {b, 0, 3}
  ] ~Flatten~ 1;

TableForm[tab, TableHeadings -> {None, {"a", "b", "x", "y", "value"}}]
```

[image]

If wish to use specific values rather than a range you merely need this syntax for [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html):

[image]

For example:

```
aVals = RandomInteger[{0, 20}, 7]
```

> ```
> {3, 9, 4, 5, 18, 13, 3}
> ```

```
expr =
  {a x + b y, 0.2 x + 0.1 y >= 14, 0.25 x + 0.6 y >= 30, 0.1 x + 0.15 y >= 10, x >= 0, y >= 0};

tab =
  Table[
    {a, b, x, y, #} /. #2 & @@ NMinimize[expr, {x, y}],
    {a, aVals}, {b, 0, 3}
  ] ~Flatten~ 1;

TableForm[tab, TableHeadings -> {None, {"a", "b", "x", "y", "value"}}]
```

[image]

---

### Explanation

[brama](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11116/brama) requested an explanation of this code:

> I have trouble understanding the role of `#2` and `~Flatten~ 1`. Also, How does it transfer the optimal `x` and `y` values from the NMinimize to the table?

The documentation for [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NMinimize.html) states:

[image]

The first part is the minimum value found, and the second part is a list of [replacement rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html).

I used the combination of [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html), [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html), and [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) to handle these two parts.  An independent example:

```
{a, b, x, y, #} /. #2 & @@ {"part1", "part2"} // Quiet
```

> ```
> {a, b, x, y, "part1"} /. "part2"
> ```

(I used [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Quiet.html) to suppress the message informing us that `"part2"` is not a list of replacement rules.)

With actual output from `NMimimize`: `{0., {x -> 55., y -> 30.}}` this becomes:

> ```
> {a, b, x, y, 0.} /. {x -> 55., y -> 30.}
> ```

Then after the [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) replacements and evaluation of `a` and `b` within `Table`:

> ```
> {0, 0, 55., 30., 0.}
> ```

See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55830/121) for other ways to work with the output of `NMinimze`.

The final piece of the code is `~Flatten~ 1`.  First: `a ~op~ b` is infix notation for `op[a, b]`.  [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html) is used to combine expressions with the same head (by default [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/List.html)) and different levels.  Here it is used to combine the lists of solutions for each `a` value into a single list of solutions.  An independent example:

```
x1 = Array[Plus, {3, 4, 5}]
```

> ```
> {{{3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}},
>  {{4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11}},
>  {{5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11}, {8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}}
> ```

```
x1 ~Flatten~ 1
```

> ```
> {{3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
>  {4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
>  {5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
>  {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
>  {4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
>  {5,6, 7, 8, 9},
>  {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
>  {7, 8, 9, 10, 11},
>  {5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
>  {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
>  {7, 8, 9, 10, 11},
>  {8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}
> ```

Comment: The first one is closer to what I want. I'd like to make a table with the next columns: a|b|x|y|Optimal Value|

Comment: @YoJesseP Please see the update.

Comment: Yeah!!! this is exactly what I want! thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @YoJesseP I am glad I could help.  If this is a fully satisfying answer please consider [Accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) it, though also consider waiting a while to give others a chance to answer too before the question appears concluded.

Comment: @YoJesseP I modified the code of my final method to hopefully make it easier to read and reuse.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard, it looks like easier to read. What if a and b don't behave as increasing parameters? could I define random values to this parameters and make the same  table? For example, instead of {a,0,3} .. having  as a random value between 0 and 20.

Comment: @YoJesseP Yes, that's a simple matter.  I'll add an example.

Comment: I've just seen your example @Mr.Wizard Thank you, I'm new using mathematica and I realize that is a powerful tool to learn and program mathematical isues. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Your third formulation is very elegant. However, I have trouble understanding the role of `#2` and `~Flatten~ 1`. Also, How does it transfer the optimal `x` and `y` values from the NMinimizer to the table? Will you please add a sentence or two to explain these in your response?

Comment: @brama Explanation appended.  It's a bit more than an sentence or two. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's more than an "effort", big +1.

Comment: @Öskå Thanks!  Since you're feeling charitable and I'm not above begging for votes this answer could use some attention (if you like it, of course!): [(55830)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55830)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I feel charitable everyday :D