# Plot Epilog FindMaximum

Tags: plotting, graphics

So I have this:

```
a=14;
max = FindMaximum[x^3 - a x^2 - x + 1, {x, -2, 15}]
 (* {1.01781, {x -> -0.0355787}}*)
```

And I plotted this:

```
Plot[f1[a, x], {x, -.5, .5}, Epilog -> 
      {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[{-0.0355786613147075`, 1.0178118484082224`}]}]
```

But it's not neat enough. So I tried to put in `max` in the commands.

```
Plot[f1[a, x], {x, -.5, .5}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[{max}]}]
```

But it failed since `max`

```
Coordinate {1.0178118484082224`, {$CellContext`x -> -0.0355786613147075}} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
```

Answer (score 3):

It's easy when you apply slots and rules:

```
point = {x /. Last[#], First[#]} &@max;
a=14;
f1[a_, x_]:= x^3 - a x^2 - x + 1;
Plot[f1[a, x], {x, -.5, .5}, 
Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[point]}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"x", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(1\)]\)(a,x)"}, 
BaseStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> Medium]]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand:
 `point = {x /. Last[#], First[#]} &@max;`

you're creating list, but the # &@max is what I don't understand.

Comment: This basically means {apply the rule from the last element of `#` to `x`, take the first element of `#`}, where `#` is an argument and `&` ends a definition of a function. `@` works almost the same as [] so, for instance, Sin[x] is the same as Sin@x (but in general `@` has different evaluation order, take a look on its documentation). Try to read sth about slots (`#`), maybe it will clear things out for you. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 14;
f[a_, x_] := x^3 - a x^2 - x + 1;
max = FindMaximum[f[a, x], {x, -2, 15}];

pnt = Reverse[Last @@@ max];
Plot[f1[a, x], {x, -.5, .5}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[pnt]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Mesh` instead of `Epilog`:

```
Plot[f1[a, x], {x, -.5, .5}, Frame->True, Mesh->{{{pnt[[1]], Directive[PointSize[.03], Blue]}}}]
(* you can also use max[[2, 1, -1]] instead of pnt[[1]] *)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice use of `Last @@@ max`.  I don't see other people using [that property](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7011/121) often enough.

Comment: @Mr.W, recently used in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60158/125) to a question marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another method is a [destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8399/121) pattern:

```
max /. {y_, {_ -> x_}} :> {x, y}
```

> ```
> {-0.0355787, 1.01781}
> ```

For a more complete handling see:  [Replacing more than one element from a Sublist](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55819/replacing-more-than-one-element-from-a-sublist/55830#55830)