# Finding maximum value with position from Table of values

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, list-manipulation, maximum

I have this table of values, how do I find the maximum value? i.e. find $z_{max}(x,y)$

```
tt1 = Table[Solve[z^2 == x^2 y - z, z, Method -> Reduce], {x, 0, 5, 1}, {y, 0, 
    5, 1}]
```

By visual inspection, clearly max $z$ occurs at the most bottom right element in matrix, $z = \frac{1}{2}(-1 + \sqrt{501}) $

How do I get *Mathematica* to read out the position and value of maximum z?

I tried using:

```
Max[tt1]
```

but it didn't work..

Comment: Remove the `// MatrixForm`.

Comment: `tt1 = Table[z /. Solve[z^2 == x^2 y - z, z, Method -> Reduce], {x, 0, 5, 1}, {y, 0, 5, 1}]; Max[tt1]`. Screenshot [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YRIUD.png).

Comment: For pedagogical purposes, in addition to removing MatrixForm as Oska mentioned, you need to convert your Rules to values, which is what the `z /. ...` modification is doing.

Comment: @Öskå That works, but how do I tell what's the value of (x,y) at that point?

Comment: A ref: [functions that return rules](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706), which elaborates on Oska's comment.

Comment: This might interest you: [(55433)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55433)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/finding-maximum-value-with-position-from-table-of-values#comment161866_56389) the following becomes too long to be just a comment so here you go:

```
tt1 = Table[
   z /. Solve[z^2 == x^2 y - z, z, Method -> Reduce], {x, 0, 5,1}, {y, 0, 5, 1}];
Max[tt1]
Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 5, 1}, {y, 0, 5, 1}][[Sequence @@ (First@Position[tt1, Max[tt1]])[[;; 2]]]]
```

> ```
> 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[501])
> {5, 5}
> ```

Comment: That's brilliant!

Comment: @user44840 I'm glad you like it :) It's nothing fancy really :)

Answer (score 3):

We can adapt [Sjoerd's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/57/sjoerd-c-de-vries) solution to the question, [Table - find index of the maximum element](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40939/table-find-index-of-the-maximum-element).  Other methods may be found here: [List manipulation: position & max value combination](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40231/list-manipulation-position-max-value-combination).

```
tt1 = Flatten[
   Table[Thread@{x, y, z /. Solve[z^2 == x^2 y - z, z, Method -> Reduce]},
    {x, 0, 5, 1}, {y, 0, 5, 1}],
   2];
```

Then this yields `{x, y, max}`:

```
tt1 ~Part~ Last @ Ordering @ tt1[[All, 3]]
(*
  {5, 5, 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[501])}
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment but... For your specific setup this can be a way with a v10 function:

```
tt1 = Table[Solve[z^2 == x^2 y - z, z, Method -> Reduce], {x, 0, 5, 1}, {y, 0, 5, 1}]
With[{v = z /. tt1}, With[{m = Max[v]}, {m, Most@FirstPosition[v, m]}]]
```

But... Why don't you solve analitically the problem? The command

```
z /. Solve[z^2 == x^2 y - z, z]
```

gives

```
{1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[1 + 4 x^2 y]), 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 x^2 y])}
```

so it's not surprising the maximum is located at lower-right corner of the matrix, where $x=y=5$, and here

```
%[[2]] /. {x -> 5, y -> 5}
```

gives:

```
1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[501])
```